# How to assign credit to the original author while referencing his solution to another question incase accepted by OP

Tags: discussion, duplicates, flagging

I have answered a question by referencing a solution to another question. If the original poster accepts my answer (to show others their question has been solved) is there any way of assigning credit to the original author of the solution I referenced?

Comment: you could award a bounty on the original question and award it to the referenced answer. (This question should be on meta.tex.sx not here)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Bounty as 'thank you'?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2971/5764)

Comment: Mention [`Author name` whose solution helped OP and give a Title of Q](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/175887/revisions). If it works for OP, in separate comment leave a comment " Possible Duplicate of `X` Q " and flag Q as duplicate for mod attention. If you choose to answer with more description/Links proceed with full answer since they exceed comment's space. Also Refer [Quick & easy reputation vs. flagging a question as duplicate](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3397/15717) and [Closing questions as exact duplications: 'best practice'](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2770/15717)